# Git tag command filtered branch name

Tags: git

How to filter tag with branch name?

```
git tag -a | grep branch <name>
```

Expected result: tag filter with git Branch or list of all tag and Branch

Comment: Problem is, you're assuming 1 tag = 1 branch. But a tag could point to a commit which is reachable by many branches (or none, for that matter). Or am I mistaken here in what you want? Could you try to post an expected output example?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks, Example:
Branch A,B . tag For A:xyz when git  branch --list | grep branch name AND for this branch tag name  as return